# ARM: different ways to transfer data from core registers to other registers

Tags: gcc, assembly, arm, cpu-registers, armv7

As far as I know there are a number of different ways to transfer data from ARM core registers (`R` registers) to other registers. I have found these two ways:

1. Transfer from core registers to co-processor registers using `MCR` instruction
2. Transfer from core registers to `D` registers using `VMOV` instruction

I need to go through each way and find out the latency of each. But for now, I'd like to know if there are any other ways to transfer data from core registers to other registers (not memory) that I might have forgotten.

My architecture is ARMv7-A and I am using GCC 4.6.3.

Comment: is this a homework assignment?  Everything you want to know is either in the ARM ARM or the TRM for that architecture.  You can very quickly go through each instruction.

Comment: No, this is not. I am making some changes to an ARM model that I am working on.
Yeah, I went through the architecture reference manual and this is what I have found. I just want to make sure I have not missed anything important since I am new to this.

Comment: I would search for cpsr or spsr or just psr in the manual to see if you see anything else.  mrc/mcr are the typical functions, the way in and out of a coprocessor (if you examine the old fpa instructions I think they were just coprocessor instructions that had been named)

Answer (score 1):

Instruction timing is micro-architecture specific (i.e. different implementations of the ARMv7 architecture will have different latencies).

You'll need to look in the TRM for the specific processor(s) you are targeting to find the latencies for each implementation.